# Java swagger codegen with enum keys in map

Tags: java, swagger

I have this object as a request body in my code:

```
@Builder
@Value
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true, access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@AllArgsConstructor
@Serdeable
@Introspected
public class ForecastingRequest {
    @NotNull
    Map<Targeting, List<Condition>> targetings;
    Map<TargetingProperties, String> properties;
    @NotNull
    Explode explode;
    @NotNull
    Double budget;
}
```

but swagger only generates this for the maps, the key is totally missing:

```
   targetings:
      additionalProperties:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Condition'
    properties:
      additionalProperties:
        type: string
```

How can I generate the proper maps with enum keys?